# SAMD21 SERCOM / UART problem: cannot enable RX and TX

Tags: microcontroller, uart, arm, programming, samd21

I've been trying to set up a USART on an `ATSAMD21E18A-MU` and have been running into issues.

Currently, I've narrowed the problem down to the fact that `CTRLB.RXEN` and `CTRLB.TXEN` never go high after enabling the USART.

My hardware has TX on `PA04` and RX on `PA06`. I'm trying to use `OSC8M` as a source for `Generator 3`, and `Generator 3` for `SERCOM0_CORE`. Trying to get everything relevant running at 8MHz.

I'm trying to set up 8n1, asynchronous mode, fractional baud rate, 16x oversampling, etc.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jkiv/81651ea6e77229aa2ff03eda5fe4da78/05d1d06661190918853927f9ec3a90708167d190) for the full example.

From the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM_D21_DA1_Family_DataSheet_DS40001882F.pdf), info on `CTRLB.RXEN` reads:

> Writing '1' to CTRLB.RXEN when the USART is disabled will set
>   CTRLB.RXEN immediately. When the USART is enabled, CTRLB.RXEN will be
>   cleared, and SYNCBUSY.CTRLB will be set and remain set until the
>   receiver is enabled. **When the receiver is enabled, CTRLB.RXEN will read
>   back as '1'.**

(There is similar text for `CTRLB.TXEN`.)

I spin check these flags after I enable the USART (line 115 and 116 in the gist) but they never go high.

Simple question: *what am I missing*?

I feel like I picked over the datasheet with a fine toothed comb...

Any and all help appreciated.

EDIT: discovered an issue with my use of `PORT_WRCONFIG_PINMASK` in the example code (e.g. `PORT_WRCONFIG_PINMASK(4)` vs. `PORT_WRCONFIG_PINMASK(1<<4)`) but currently does not resolve the issue.

Comment: My guess is there's some clock enable or peripheral enable bit that was missed. Usually these digital comm peripherals need you to feed it a clock signal, and/or turn on some enable bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging deeper, the issue was that `CTRLA.MODE` [was set to *external* clock source](https://gist.github.com/jkiv/81651ea6e77229aa2ff03eda5fe4da78/05d1d06661190918853927f9ec3a90708167d190#file-main-c-L88) (i.e. `XCK` on `PAD[2]` where no clock is connected), rather than an internal clock source.

Additionally, `CTRLA.DORD` was set to MSB-first, whereas my linux endpoint prefers LSB-first.

The [gist has been updated](https://gist.github.com/jkiv/81651ea6e77229aa2ff03eda5fe4da78) for a working "Hello, World!"

Comment: I'm glad you posted the solution. I looked through the code but couldn't see what the issue was.

Answer (score -2):

Almost all microcontroller have the ADC input pins set as analog by default,  you need to set the pins that you  need for the uart as digital.